# Clip Play + volumeControl = a Pop

Tags: java, javasound

I have searched and searched, and have not found the cause of my problem.

**Setting:**  I am trying to play a list of clips in sequence indefinitely till the GUI of the program tells to stop.  Also, the user can adjust the volume while the clips are being played.
Let's say I have clips A, B and C.  The sequence of play will be ABCABCABCABC.....

**Problem:**  The problem is that the first time clips A, B and C start - there are POPs - after that for the GUI tells to stop, there are no POPs.

**Code:** In the run() method of the thread, get all filenames of the clips, create all clips and save them in a LinkedHashSet.  Next, play these clips in loop, creating the volume control object for each.

**My Observation:**  The offending lines are commented (with // TODO:  UNCOMMENT ME!!!!!)  With the commented lines, there are no POPs, but the volume control is disabled.  When these lines are uncommented, the POPs return.

**Question:**  Where am I going wrong?  I don't have any hair on the head to pull out! :)

```
    private LinkedHashSet<Clip> clips = new LinkedHashSet<Clip>();
    private FloatControl volControl = null;
    .
    .
    .
    .
    @Override
    public void run() {
        List<String> fileNames = smd.getFiles();

        if ( !(numFiles.isEmpty()) ) {
            try {
                // Create all clips and save in LinkedHashSet
                //
                for (String s: fileNames) {
                    clips.add(CreateClip(s));
                }

                // Play each clip till GUI says to stop
                //
                while (smd.getStopPlayStatus()) {
                    for (Clip c: clips) {

                        // Calculate and set the clip volume to what GUI says
                        //
                        float dB = (float) (Math.log(smd.getSwarMVolume()/100f) / Math.log(10.0) * 80.0);
                        System.out.println("  vol = " + volumeLevel/100f + " || dB = " + dB);
                        Control[ ] ctls = c.getControls();
                        for (Control ctl : ctls) {
                            if (ctl.toString().toLowerCase().contains("master gain")) {
                                volControl = (FloatControl) ctl;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
//                      volControl.setValue(dB); // TODO:   UNCOMMENT ME!!!!!!!!

                        //  Play the clip
                        //
                        loop(c, 0);
                    }
                }
            } catch (ConcurrentModificationException ex) { 
            } 
        }
    }



    void loop(Clip clip, int times){
        if (times == -1) {
            clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
        } else {
            clip.loop(times);
        }
        while (clip.isRunning()) {
            float dB = (float) (Math.log(smd.getVolume()/100f) / Math.log(10.0) * 80.0);
//          volControl.setValue(dB); // TODO:   UNCOMMENT ME!!!!!!!!

            try {
                Thread.sleep(50);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
        clip.drain();
    }


    private Clip CreateClip(String fileName) {
        Clip c = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);

            AudioInputStream sound = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(file);
            AudioFormat format = sound.getFormat();
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(Clip.class, format);
            c = (Clip) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            c.addLineListener(this);

            c.open(sound);

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        } 
        return c;
    }
```

Comment: What device / OS? This sounds like a low-level bug that might be out of your control.

Comment: I am developing on OS X.  A low-level bug like this is scary!

Comment: You could start by checking you are not getting any of the exceptions that you are ignoring - never ignore exceptions.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for the suggestion.  I had made sure that there are no exceptions in my testing.  After that I chose to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

The volume controls that are provided are very crude. When you set a new volume, the entire change happens all at once. This can create a discontinuity in the sound that results in a pop.

To eliminate this, one can try making the volume change more gradually. Sometimes this works. You will have to tinker with it to find the best trade-off of the amount of time needed for a transition and smoothness.

There are several issues that pertain. (1) The "distance" one can travel in a single volume change without a pop can be different at the low end versus the high end, depending on the scaling in use. (2) The number of changes you can make over a period of time is limited by the buffer size. You can only make one change per buffer. Thus decreasing the buffer size will allow more granularity in the volume changes, but will increase the risk of drop-outs.

Frankly, I just threw up my hands and gave up using the provided volume lines. Instead, I program the changes to transition on a per-frame basis. This can be done by taking each buffer and converting the bytes to PCM, doing the volume multiplication on the individual frames and converting back to bytes. The processing cost turns out to be pretty minor.

Comment: Thanks, Phil, for your insight.  I have read several of your informative "suggestions".  One thing I did not mention in my question is that, for the initial three (in this case) pops, I am not trying to adjust the volume. So, I, not being that familiar with audio formats and such, am  stuck. Thanks again!!.

Comment: Quite welcome. I hope I'm actually being helpful. One thing more to consider: the first time you set a line, that could cause a pop if the line has a default value that is different, or the sound without the line has a default that is different. But having not taken the time to try your code, I couldn't say for sure this is the issue. Just a guess.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. In case my last comment was not clear, I was suggesting ramping up to the volume setting from 0, rather than starting at a given volume with the line. And/or: perhaps set the value prior to launching the Clip. I'd also as a diagnostic check, send the db values to a file or stdout to check whether or not there are any large jumps in that value.

Comment: I have dumped the db values to stdout and they look fine.  The dilemma I am facing is that the user can choose different clips in the GUI and the player has to respond to those changes seamlessly. So, while clips ABC, for example, being played, user can deselect them & choose DEF. The transition from ABC to DEF has to be seamless (in terms of volume) and I know that with the POPs, I can't achieve that.  Also, have to say that the clips are very short - 1 to 2 seconds; therefore, not enough time to increase volume gradually. Bummer!

Comment: Last thought: rerecord the cues and cheat the in and out volumes. Since cues are so short, can hold them in memory as PCM and mix them on per-byte basis (allows very quick ramps, e.g., 100 frames is 1/44th of a second) and send out via SourceDataLine. This is what I do.